# Why is it 'Как зовут сына Илоны?' and not 'Как зовут сын Илоны?'?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

I'm fairly new at studying russian but I came across this example in my workbook:

'Как зовут сына Илоны?' and right next to it 'Как зовут дочь Илоны?'

I know that 'Илоны' is genitive and the word its referring to should be in nominative, right?

For being plural, there should be a number in front of it like 'два'.
So what am I missing here? Why is 'сына' in genetive but not 'дочь'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is best to analyse sentences beginning with the verb.
 In *Как зовут сына Илоны?* the verb is *зовут* and it is in the **3rd person plural** which means its subject should also be plural. But there are no plural nouns in this sentence which means the subject is *they* and it is omitted, *зовут* means '[they] call', this sentence is **impersonal**, that is, without an explicit subject. That is how Russian works when it comes to asking someone's name, *Как тебя/Вас зовут?* is actually 'How do they call you?' where *тебя/Вас* is the **direct object** and it is, naturally, in the **accusative case**.

Your sentence works just the same way.
 *Сына* is the direct object in the accusative case. Since *cын* is a masculine animate noun, its accusative case = genitive case. If *дочь* is used instead, it will be in the accusative case too, but since *дочь* belongs to the 3rd noun declension (feminine nouns ending in a consonant + ь), its accusative case = nominative case.
 *Илоны* is in genitive since it is an attribute to *cын*, *cын Илоны* is 'the son of Ilona.'

*Как зовут сына Илоны?* is 'How do.they.call the.son of.Ilona?' if translated word for word, where the subject 'they' is omitted since the verb *зовут* is impersonal, the direct object, the animate masculine noun *сын* 'son', is in the accusative case, and *Илоны* is in genitive case, 'of Ilona; Ilona's.'

There is a [similar question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7537) on Russian SE.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that 'Илоны' is genitive and the word its referring to should be in nominative, right?

Not right. The word which is referred by a word in genitive can be in any case:

- Ко мне подошёл сын Илоны (nominative).
- Меня укусила собака сына Илоны (genitive).
- Я иду в гости к сыну Илоны (dative).
- Как зовут сына Илоны? Сына Илоны зовут Макс (accusative).
- Вся улица гордится сыном Илоны (instrumental).
- В газете написали о сыне Илоны (prepositional).

It is not unusual in scientific and official speech to have many genitives one after other.

Comment: @VerkhocevaKatya у меня так и написано же

Comment: @VerkhocevaKatya а, теперь понял. Тогда вместо "исправно" должно быть другое слово, скорее всего "верно" или "правильно". "Исправно" означает "не сломано, работает как надо" :)

Comment: In your 4th example, it's better to put that question mark _before_ "(accusative)", because some people can think the question mark refers to which case it is, that you're not sure whether it is accusative.

Comment: @YellowSky right.

Answer (score 2):

It is accusative, just like in most of the Slavic languages and it is gender-sensitive and there is no reflexive pronoun.